# Get Current Params to concat with Url in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my Ruby application i have a destroy method on a class Transaction to delete its record, which is working fine. Here is the function

```
def destroy
  @transaction = Transaction.find(params[:id])
  @transaction.destroy
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to transactions_url }
  end
end
```

And call to function is like this

```
#{button_to 'Destroy', t, confirm: 'Are you sure?', method: :delete, :class => "buttonAslink"}
```

I have a Filter function which filter records on some condition. After filtering when i delete a record it redirect to root Url and show all records instead of filtered only.

So i want to get query string parameters to attach to the url so that after deletion page redirect to same location so that only filter records should show.

Please guide me on this

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First add filter param in your button_to:

```
#{button_to 'Destroy', transaction_path(:id=>t.id,:filter=>'conditions'), confirm: 'Are you sure?', method: :delete, :class => "buttonAslink"}
```

Then just append them to the options:

```
format.html { redirect_to transactions_url(:parameter => params[:filter]) }
```

Would yield */transactions?parameter=conditions*

Comment: zolter, thanks for your reply, actually the parameters are very large in numbers